# IOS:Reading Peripheral values in string format

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

i am doing corebluetooth application.i have written code for writing values to the peripheral and getting response from it.Problem is i am not knowing in which format jam getting the values i have seen in the console as below.

```
2014-12-23 17:06:39.276 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] Updated notification state for   

characteristic 8882 (newState:Notifying)

2014-12-23 17:06:39.276 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] value notified is <010c5700 0101180f 
 140fdcfb>

2014-12-23 17:06:39.277 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] value notified is 8882

 2014-12-23 17:06:39.277 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] didWriteValueForCharacteristic

 2014-12-23 17:06:39.277 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] characteristic.UUID : 8882

 2014-12-23 17:06:39.278 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] characteristic.value : <010c5700 
 0101180f 140fdcfb>
 2014-12-23 17:06:39.334 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] didUpdateValueForCharacteristic
 2014-12-23 17:06:39.335 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] characteristic.UUID : 8882
 2014-12-23 17:06:39.336 Bluetooth_iph[596:84992] characteristic.value : <010c5700    
 0101180f 140fdcfb>
```

please help how to retrieve the value in the string format .As example i have given command for the battery status so that i am getting that value.So i must retrieve the data in string format.

Comment: What type of peripheral service are you reading?  What is the definition of the characteristic. The value doesn't appear to be an ASCII string. You need to refer to the device/service spredications in order to understand how to interpret the data values

Comment: i have service of 8880 and characterstic of 8882 its giving battery status in this format  <010c5700    
 0101180f 140fdcfb> so i need to convert to show how much battery has ""percentage Ex:80 percentage .how its possible to show that and .As i have understand u in above point u are asking me to know about how to read the values provided by peripheral from the manufacturer right?

Comment: That's right. Those aren't the standard battery service/characteristic defined by the Bluetooth forum. You will need information from the device manufacturer

Comment: i have given one string and getting value as @"\x01\x119" the value is correct and i need to print in the console but when i am giving %@ the value is giving as "q"(no quotes) please help me instead of that q

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What are you printing with %@? An NSData?

Comment: characterstic.value i have kept in Nsdata so its giving me 17 bytes.And That data i am giving to Nsstringby encoding it And when i am printing that value i am getting value as ""q""

Comment: Yes, well from the information you have posted the NsData doesn't contain printable characters, so I am not surprised that it doesn't print out anything meaningful. You probably need to convert it to an array of bytes. Without the manufacturer specification on the data I can't suggest much more